# Invalid Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, regular-language

I have this regex:

```
private final String CUSTOM_REGEX = "[679]\d{8}";
```

It should represent **any number starting from 6, 7 or 9, that has eight numbers more**. (i.e "`611234392`", "`782123842`" or "`934233875`")

However, I am getting an error `"Invalid scape sequence"`

Any hint?

Comment: Use double backslash: `"[679]\\d{8}"`

Comment: @anubhava How would you put a +34 before to accept numbers with that optional prefix? (i.e "+34675645123" and "675645123" will both be valid) I tried "{+34}?[679]\\d{8}" but it's not working.

Comment: It will be: `"(\\+34)?[679]\\d{8}"`

Comment: [It definitely works](https://regex101.com/r/iX5uS2/1) You need to show some how it is not working for you.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry mate, my mistake. It is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
private final String SPANISH_NUMBER_REGEX = "[679]\\d{8}";
                                                  ^^
```

Why?

In Java in String literal you have to escape `\` with one more `\` because it itself is a special character and needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks man. How would you put a +34 before to accept numbers with that optional prefix? (i.e "+34675645123" and "675645123" will both be valid) I tried "{+34}?[679]\\d{8}" but it's not working

Comment: @stackpepe use `([+]34)?[679]\\d{8}`

Answer (score 2):

```
String SPANISH_NUMBER_REGEX = "[679]\d{8}";
```

`\` is a special character in String literals, namely the escape character. You need to escape it to get the correct result:

```
String SPANISH_NUMBER_REGEX = "[679]\\d{8}";
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash character `\` serves to introduce escaped constructs, as well as to quote characters that otherwise would be interpreted as unescaped constructs. Thus the expression `\\` matches a single backslash and `\{` matches a left brace.

From official Oracle Docs: [Backslashes, escapes, and quoting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs).